# get Manager from Outlook Contacts using VBA

Tags: vba, outlook, mapi

I have the below code that retrieves the Global Address List from Outlook then creates an array with the name and the department.

I'd like to get the users manager - but I can't find it in the list of properties and  `oUser.GetExchangeUserManager` doesn't work

```
    Dim appOL As Outlook.Application ' Object
    Dim oGAL As Outlook.AddressEntries ' .NameSpace  Object
    Dim oContact As Outlook.AddressEntry ' Object
    Dim oUser As ExchangeUser ' Object
    Dim arrUsers(1 To 65000, 1 To 4) As String
    Dim UserIndex As Long
    Dim i As Long

    Set appOL = New Outlook.Application ' CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set oGAL = appOL.GetNameSpace("MAPI").AddressLists("Global Address List").AddressEntries

    For i = 1 To oGAL.Count
        Set oContact = oGAL.Item(i)
        If oContact.AddressEntryUserType = 0 Then
            Set oUser = oContact.GetExchangeUser
            If Len(oUser.lastname) > 0 Then
                UserIndex = UserIndex + 1
                arrUsers(UserIndex, 1) = oUser.Name
                arrUsers(UserIndex, 2) = oUser.Department
                arrUsers(UserIndex, 3) = oUser.JobTitle ' Blank
                'arrUsers(UserIndex, 4) = oUser.GetExchangeUserManager  ' ERROR         
            End If
        End If
    Next i

    appOL.Quit

    If UserIndex > 0 Then
        Range("A2").Resize(UserIndex, UBound(arrUsers, 2)).Value = arrUsers
    End If

    Set appOL = Nothing
    Set oGAL = Nothing
    Set oContact = Nothing
    Set oUser = Nothing
    Erase arrUsers

End Sub
```

any thoughts on how to get the manager info?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `AddressEntry.Manager` - it will return another `AddressEntry` object that represents the manager. Be prepared to handle `Null`s.

Comment: thanks, but in my code above I am using the `AddressEntry` in my `oContact` object variable. When I put a fullstop or period after oContact to see the list of Members, there is no Manager item in the list of members

Comment: AddressEntry.Manager was exposed as far back as Outlook 2000 (I did not check the prior versions). If the property is hidden, Intellisense will not show it. Try to type it in your code and use it anyway.